# Homebrew: Safe to remove .git folder in homebrew-core/homebrew-cask folder?

Tags: homebrew

Is it safe to delete the .git folder in homebrew-core/homebrew-cask? It takes up like 1GB of my disk and I def won't contribute to brew using git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2365), it is safe to untap (aka remove) the homebrew-core and homebrew-cask taps, and then you manage the formulae/casks using `HOMEBREW_INSTALL_FROM_API`.